# Devemos evitar dependências circulares?

Tags: angularjs

Quando trabalhamos com AngularJS é muito comum termos aplicações onde os services contenham apenas chamadas HTTP para o servidor que irá armazenar os dados. Porém, numa aplicação onde não teremos um servidor nosso service poderá ser responsável por muitas lógicas de negócio (não se preocupem em o código ficar visível para o usuário) e devido a isso um service poderá chamar outro e vice versa (isso é má pratica).

Imaginem a seguinte situação:

```
angular.module('app').service('logAPI',[ function('fileManager') {

    var _logList = [];

    var LogMessage = function(system, type, message, value, now) {
        this.system = system;
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
        this.value = value;
        this.time = now;
    };

    this.scheduleLogMessage = function(system, type, message, value) {
        if (_logList.length < 300) {
            var now = utilAPI.getFormattedTime();
            var log = new LogMessage(system, type, message, value);
            _logList.push(log);
        }
    };

    this.processLog = function() {
        if (_logList.length >= 200) {
            fileManager.upload(_logList[0]);
        }
    };  

}])

.service('fileManager',[ function('storageAPI') {

    var upload = function(obj) {
        storageAPI.upload(obj).then(function success() {
            logAPI.scheduleLogMessage('a', 'a', 'a', 'a');
        }, function error() {
            logAPI.scheduleLogMessage('a', 'a', 'a', 'a');
        })
    }

}])

.controller('appCtrl', ['', function('logAPI'){


    while(true) {
        logAPI.processLog();
    }

}]);
```

O angularJS acusará de dependência circular. Existem meios de burlar isso e o angular 'ignorar' essa dependência, porém, isso é uma má prática ? Devemos evitar?

> Edição: Melhora do exemplo

Meu **logAPI** é responsável por gerenciar todo log gerado pelo sistema e depois de uma quantidade X de mensagem, ele começa a fazer o upload desses logs. Quando o upload é feito, ele também pode gerar log para registrar o oque aconteceu. Em geral, tudo no meu sistema gera LOG e por causa disso, eu não consigo pensar numa maneira de quebrar essa dependencia.

Comment: Tlz ajude, [Gerenciamento de Memória](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

Comment: Fiz alteração da resposta. Verifique se atende o que você precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor maneira que conheço de evitar referência circular, é criar um módulo à parte, onde fiquem as regras de negocio que são comuns a um ou mais serviços. Não levando apenas ao mundo do Angular. 
No blog do [Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/about/), um dos autores do angular, ele cita exatamente isso.

Segue o link para consulta:
[Blog](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/)

### Edição:

A ideia de um logger é que ele seja como um container de logs e ele se responsabilize por logar tudo.
Já o seu `fileManager` tem que dar respostas do que ele fez e não logar.

Sendo assim, podemos usar promises dentro do `fileManager` e devolver uma resposta à `logApi`, que é responsável por logar.

A estrutura abaixo é mais ou menos um esboço do que queremos. (Desculpe-me o desenho, tive q fazer no paint)

[image: Diagrama]

E aqui segue um [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4awmh27d/1/) com um exemplo para você se basear.
Quando clicar no botão "LOGAR" do exemplo, abra o console do navegador

Espero que o ajude

Comment: Baseado na minha opinião sobre referência circular, fui pesquisar e em um link do stackoveflow americano foi onde encontrei o blog do Misko Hevery. Achei muito válido colocar aqui.

Comment: Fiz as edições baseado no que você alterou.

Comment: Acho que sua solução vai funcionar para mim, porém, tenho algumas dúvidas. 1. Como você acessa {{vm.resultado}} sendo que no seu controller você não tem nenhum $scope.vm.resultado, 2. O que você retorna de fileManager é uma promise?

Comment: 1. Na função MainController, atribuo uma variável `self`, que representa o controller. Isso me faz evitar ter que acessar o `$scope`. Na verdade é uma técnica de `Binding`, que, em outras linguagens de programação, é implicita. Tem mais informações sobre isso aqui: http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations

2. Sim

Comment: Vou testar aqui, gostei da solução. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Disponha! Estamos todos aqui pra isso. Abraço

Comment: Da pra retornar uma promise de uma chamada http? tipo, ali tu retornou uma promise da chamada de uma função ali, mas e em vez da promise, eu tivesse que ainda fazer um http.get, como ficaria? Eu tentei testar aqui mas não rolou, https://jsfiddle.net/4awmh27d/2/

Comment: Sim, no caso vc deve retornar o proprio `$http.get`, que já é uma promise, veja o exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/4awmh27d/3/